# Expressing Java Annotation Class with Members in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, osgi, apache-felix

I'm new to Kotlin and currently using v1.3.31 in an OSGI bundle development POC. I'm currently using annotation processors to generate the OSGI manifest declarations and I am trying to find the **Kotlin equivalent** of the following:

```java
@ObjectClassDefinition(name="Config", description = "Sample Config")
    public static @interface Config {
        @AttributeDefinition(name = "A parameter", description = "Configurable param")
        String myParameter() default "";
    }
```

Given that these OSGI annotations are created as:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ObjectClassDefinition

/*....*/

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface AttributeDefinition
```

The closest I can get in Kotlin is using the `@ObjectClassDefinition` annotation on a `public annotation class` but since Kotlin annotation classes do not support members, I cannot use the `@AttributeDefinition` on a class member.

- I've tried to only use a Kotlin `class` or `interface` but the annotation processor will not allow any non-annotation class.
- I've also tried to create a `java.lang.Annotation` in Kotlin to bypass this behavior, but the compiler will not allow it.

Current partially working implementation and here's is the latest working [GitHub source.](https://github.com/GuillaumeC91/sling-kotlin-samples/blob/5dfabad73810433fa5c4a0b17e11a61b2580e755/core/src/main/java/com/github/guillaumec91/core/servlets/SimpleKotlinServlet.kt):

```java
@ObjectClassDefinition(name = "Sample Kotlin servlet",
            description = "Simple Kotlin servlet with configurable properties")
    public annotation class  Config (
        val value : String = "hello"
    )
```

I've noticed that annotations can be particularly tricky in Kotlin. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ObjectClassDefinition(
    name = "Sample Kotlin servlet",
    description = "Simple Kotlin servlet with configurable properties")
annotation class  Config (
  @get:AttributeDefinition(name = "A parameter", description = "Configurable param")
  val value : String = "hello")
```

("public" does not seem to have any effect).
See this documentation for details [annotation-use-site-targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Used this approach to implement configurations on Kotlin-based OSGI services. Thanks.